# синтаксис javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div onclick="

if ((zamanux = 'undefined')||(zamanux=0)) {document.getElementById('zam').style.right='-75px'; zamanux=1;}

else {document.getElementById('zam').style.right='0px';  zamanux=0;}; ">
```

почему то даже после первого нажатия переменная zamanux остается не определенной... т.е. я хочу чтобы по первому нажатию свойство right менялось на -75... а по повторному возвращалось на 0... но работает только в одну сторону, а на 0 не меняется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(zamanus === undefined) {
    //чета делаем
    zamanus = true;
}
else {
   //чета делаем...
   zamanus = undefined;
}
```

типичный пример переключателя...

**UPD**
все потомучто переменная zamanus, должна быть определена в скрипте, я думал это очевидно...
ну вот вам рабочий пример:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var z = undefined;
 </script>
 <div onclick="
     if(z === undefined) {
        this.style.color='red';
        z = true;
    }
    else {
        this.style.color='';
        z = undefined;
    }
    ">
Клацни и я буду менять цвет
</div>
```

Comment: ну я и делаю так... только почему то zamunux=1 не задерживается в памяти компа... если поставить после этой строчки alert (zamanux), то на экран выскочит 1... но после этого, по нажатию должно срабатывать условие else... а почемуто все равно if работает

Comment: по вашему `zamanux = 'undefined'` и `zamanux === undefined` одно и тоже?

Comment: попробовал как вы пишите, не прокатило

Comment: if ((zamanux = 'undefined')||(zamanux=0)) {document.getElementById('zam').style.right='-75px'; alert(zamanux); zamanux=1;alert(zamanux);}
... еще раз... после первого нажатия, на экране появляется сначала 'undefined', а потом '1'... т.е. условие сработало... но при повторном нажатии переменная zamanux уже равна 1, по идее, поэтому должно сработать условие else.. но почемуто все равно работает if при этом снова выдает сначала 'undefined', а потом '1'... такое чувство что переменная не осталась в памяти после первого нажатия

Comment: смотрим выше, понимаем что в нашем случае нам нужна глобальная переменная, изменяем код - <b>profit</b>

Comment: Можно и без глобальной сделать, но вам пока лучше над этим не заморачиваться...

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function zamanuxa ()
{
if ((zamanux = 1)||(zamanux='undefined')) {document.getElementById('zam').style.right='-75px'; zamanux = 0;}
else {alert(zamanux);document.getElementById('zam').style.right='1px';  zamanux = 1;}
}
</script>

уже в отдельную функцию вынес... один фик... условие else никогда не срабатывает

Comment: Я вам дал готовое решение и вы даже этим воспользоватся не можете, учите матчасть...

Answer (score 1):

`if ((zamanux = 'undefined')||(zamanux=0))`

Вряд вы оба раза хотите **присвоить** (первый раз строку "undefined", второй - число 0).

Comment: не понял... if ((zamanux = 'undefined')||(zamanux=0)) - это условие обрабатывает две ситуации, ибо первый раз тыкнул на блок c id=zam либо 3, 5, 7

Comment: Смысла if'а в том, чтобы узнать, равен ли он нулю или undefined?

Comment: [@Нубойд](http://hashcode.ru/users/3105/нубойд), [знакомьтесь](http://javascript.ru/comparison-operators)

Comment: да... если не равен то else

Comment: Тогда рвенство всё-таки двойное)

Comment: в случае с `undefined` лучше тройное ;)